# Why SSRS formula throws error when not all parameters are selected?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

My report has 2 multi-valued parameters : TerritoryGroup and Year.

On each page, I'm displaying a Year.
On the first page, I have a page header, and a chart.
On the second page, I still have that page header, and then the report for the parametrized values.

I want the page header of the first page to show the first and the last selected Year. 
And on the subsequent pages, I want the page header to show that page Year.

The available 4 Year in my dataset are 2001,2002,2003,2004.

My problem is that the formula I made is working when the 4 Year are selected, but it throws an error when I select less than 4 Year.

Here's my formula :

```
= IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1
                ,(IIF(Parameters!Year.Count > 1
                               ,Parameters!Year.Value(0) & " - " & Parameters!Year.Value(Parameters!Year.Count-1)
                                               ,Parameters!Year.Value(0)))
                     ,IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 2
                               ,Parameters!Year.Value(0)
                                               ,IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 3
                                                               ,Parameters!Year.Value(1)
                                                                               ,IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 4
                                                                                              ,Parameters!Year.Value(2)
                                                                                                              ,IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 5
                                                                                                                              ,Parameters!Year.Value(3),"")))))
```

Could someone help me with this?
Don't hesitate if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
= switch(
Globals!PageNumber = 1 and Parameters!Year.Count = 1 , Parameters!Year.Value(0),
Globals!PageNumber = 1 and Parameters!Year.Count = 2 , Parameters!Year.Value(0) & " - 
" & (Parameters!Year.Value(0)+1),
Globals!PageNumber = 1 and Parameters!Year.Count = 3 , Parameters!Year.Value(0) & " - 
" & (Parameters!Year.Value(0)+2),
Globals!PageNumber = 1 and Parameters!Year.Count = 4 , Parameters!Year.Value(0) & " - 
" & (Parameters!Year.Value(0)+3),
Globals!PageNumber = 2 ,Parameters!Year.Value(0),
Globals!PageNumber = 3 ,Parameters!Year.Value(1),
Globals!PageNumber = 4 ,Parameters!Year.Value(2),
Globals!PageNumber = 5 ,Parameters!Year.Value(3)
)
```